# Is there a way to call functions from other functions?

Tags: python

I keep getting errors when i try to call functions from other functions (in an if statement to be exact). like:

```
    def function1(num):
        num = 5    
        if num == 5:
            function2("This is 5")
        return

    def function2(x):
        print x
        return
```

I have not been able to find any problems like this one before. Is it at all possible?

Comment: When asking questions like this, please post the traceback. The traceback is regularly enough for you to identify the issue yourself and will normally help in correct diagnosis of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: the first error was simply a typing mistake and has been corrected in the question.

Remove the colon after the line `function2("This is 5")`.

Also, you are not explicitly returning a value, so there is no reason to use a return statement at the end of your two functions.

Comment: I think it's just an oversimplified example. The first function could easily be written as `def function1(num): print("This is 5")` but I don't think that's the point.

Comment: that was just a syntax error with the example, it still doesnt work correctly.

Comment: he is also missin a colon on function2

Comment: @user1661202 as you currently have it, your program runs correctly for me in Python 2.7. I call function1(<anything>) and it prints "This is 5"

Comment: @user1661202: you won't get useful help if you don't provide enough information. "it doesn't work" isn't enough detail.  If you have an error message, provide it (all of it), or tell us more specifically how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
def function1(num):
    num = 5    
    if num == 5:
        function2("This is 5")
    return

def function2(x):
    print x
    return
```

This works for me, you put an extra colon after your call to function2 in function1 and missed a colon after function2(x)